# Simple SQL Delete statement giving timeout

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, timeout

When executing this simple SQL Delete statement, I'm getting a timeout from SQL Server:

```
DELETE FROM dbo.[User] WHERE Id = 95146
```

There are about 95.000 records in the table.

I thought it might be because of indexes on the table, so I've deleted all except from the primary key (Id) which is clustered, but this didn't help.

I've deleted all the statistics I created as well, but also without any effect.

What else can I do to optimize for this?

Kind regards,
David

Comment: Please tag and/or specify which version of SQL Server you are using. This information is always helpful, as some approaches to your problem may or may not be appropriate for certain versions.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

How many foreign keys do you have referencing the `Id` column of `Users`, and are there indexes on these columns?

If cascade is set as `NO_ACTION`, as you've indicated, the time may be being spent by SQL Server having to perform a full table scan on each of these tables to ensure that there's no reference to `Id` 95146 - I've seen this easily take minutes at a time before, if the other tables are large.

Comment: There are actually 20 of those foreign keys pointing to the user id, so I think that's the problem. I'll go through those to check the indexes.

Comment: Ok, this was the reason. After adding an index to those foreign keys, the timeout went away. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

that's very odd.  my guess is you have a ON DELETE CASCADE foreign key referencing your Users table elsewhere in your schema.  Check your constraints:

```
SELECT f.name AS ForeignKey,
    OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) AS TableName,
    COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id,fc.parent_column_id) AS ColumnName,
    OBJECT_NAME (f.referenced_object_id) AS ReferenceTableName,
    COL_NAME(fc.referenced_object_id,
    fc.referenced_column_id) AS ReferenceColumnName,
    f.delete_referential_action_desc
FROM sys.foreign_keys AS f
INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc
ON f.OBJECT_ID = fc.constraint_object_id
```

Comment: I do have foreign key references, but running the above shows all of them to have NO_ACTION in the delete_referencial_action_desc column.

Comment: They don't need to be cascading to cause problems - every value of the foreign key column needs to be checked that it doesn't contain the value you are deleting, hence if there isn't an index on that column then there will be a table scan.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I'll go through those to check.

Answer (score 4):

I was struggling with a `DELETE` statement which was causing our ERP (Epicor 10) system to timeout on its nightly run of MRP.  It was a delete with a few joins in it, and one of the tables involved in the join is quite large.  The odd thing was that if I transformed the delete to a `SELECT *` for the same joins / where clause, then the query would complete instantly, and had ZERO results (i.e. the delete statement was obviously doing some long, large table scanning but it didn't actually find anything to delete).

What finally helped was I ran the select statment version of it with *Show actual execution plan* turned on, and this had a suggested Non-Unique Index to add to one of the tables.  After I added this index, the select statement still ran instantly, but now the delete statement did as well!

Answer (score 2):

While your statement is running, take a look at the list of running tasks and locks taken out by the system.  You can get this information from Activity Monitor, or you can look at running tasks in the view [`sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188743.aspx) and locks with [`exec sp_lock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187749.aspx) and [`sys.dm_tran_locks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190345.aspx).

Also, in SQL Server Management Studio, enter this statement and look at the estimated execution plan.  Maybe you'll be able to see what SQL Server is trying to do.

Take a look at foreign keys to this table.  You may need to add some indexes on other tables to optimize foreign key assertions.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other responses, perhaps your DELETE is being blocked by some other activity (see if there is any value in the BlkBy column of sp_who2 for your spid), or perhaps there is a trigger on the table that is doing something unhealthy. Most of the things mentioned will slow the delete down, but except in extremely elaborate situations, not significantly enough to cause a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

My timeout was caused by a transaction that was not finished. I started with

```
BEGIN TRAN
```

but did not execute

```
COMMIT TRAN
```

or

```
ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same sort of problem.
My table (300k rows) could not contain primary keys and had no relationships.

- Updates freezed randomly when I updated a single row (identified by ID (not unique) and another field).
- Delete always timed-out.

The solution : change one column and set is as an index (ID in my case).

PS : Index is not the same as a primary key.